# How to deal with nonmeasurable sets when proving simple function is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, simple-functions

I know the simple function f is defined as ai if x is in a sequence of measurable set Ei, 0 if it is not in the union of Ei.

I tried to prove that simple function is measurable.

It is measurable if `B={x:f(x)<r} for all r in R` is measurable.

My concern right now is if r is declared as 1 (1>0), then the set B must include the set of {x:f(x)=0}, which is not in the union of Ei, and which may be non-measurable. 
In this case, how do we prove that the function is measurable?

Answer (score 1):

By definition a simple function is a function of the type $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}c_iE_i$ where $E_i$'s are measurable.  Note that the union of $E_1,E_2,...,E_n$ is measurable and so is the complement of this union. So the problem you are contemplating does not arise.

Let $E_0$ be the complement of the union of $E_i$'s. Then $f^{-1}(E)$ is a union of some of the sets $E_0,E_1,..,E_n$ for any Borel set $E$ in $\mathbb R$. Hence $f$ is measurable.

**Complement of measurable set is measurable by definition.**

Comment: Do you mind explain why the complement of union of Ei is measurable? I thought if we have a measurable space (X,S), only S is measurable. Union Ei complement are X-Ei, which doesn't have to be necessarily measurable. Where did I think wrong?

Comment: By the defintion of  a sigma algebra finite (or even countable) unions of measurable set  are measurable and complements of measurable sets are measurable. @yiG

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks alot!